# Howto Specify TABLOCK with the ODBC API

Tags: c++, sql, api, odbc

I'm looking into improving the performance of a bulk copy operation and it's been suggested I should add the TABLOCK option to the bulk insert statement. The question is how to do that when using the ODBC API from C++ code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to call bcp_control() and use the BCPHINTS option to specify "TABLOCK".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-extensions-bulk-copy-functions/bcp-control?view=sql-server-2017

All hints listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#h

Sample found here:

https://github.com/morungos/p5-Win32-ODBC-BulkLoader/blob/master/BulkLoader.xs